# Set tick interval on lightningchart js axis

Tags: javascript, charts, axis, lightningchart

How can I set an interval for ticks on an axis?
I've used AxisTickStrategies.Numeric but this sets the ticks automatically depending on the chart size.
On an axis range from 0 to 20 I want to set a minor tick every 2.5 and a major tick every 5 units.

Is this possible with lightningchart js?
Below code sets the tick styles but I haven't found any option to define the interval.

```
var color = '#435533';

axis.setTickStrategy(AxisTickStrategies.Numeric, (styler) =>
    styler
        .setMajorTickStyle(new VisibleTicks({
            tickStyle: new SolidLine({fillStyle: new SolidFill({ color: ColorHEX(color) }), thickness: 1 }),
            labelFillStyle: new SolidFill({ color: ColorHEX(color), tickLength: 8 }),
            gridStrokeLength: 0
        }))
        .setMinorTickStyle(new VisibleTicks({
            tickStyle: new SolidLine({fillStyle: new SolidFill({ color: ColorHEX(color) }), thickness: 1 }),
            labelFillStyle: new SolidFill({ color: ColorHEX(color), tickLength: 4 }),
            gridStrokeLength: 0
        }))
```

I have also tried CustomTick but I'm not sure if this is the right approach.

```
axis.addCustomTick().setMarker( 
    marker => marker
    .setFont(font => font
        .setSize(25)
    )
    .setBackground(background => background
        .setStrokeStyle((line) => line
            .setFillStyle(style => style
                .setColor(new SolidFill({ color : ColorHEX('#555555')}))
            )
        )
    )
).setValue(3);
```

This code sets a tick at 3 as expected but background styling doesn't work. If CustomTicks are the way to go, how can I set tickLength and background color?

Answer (score 0):

For custom ticks positioning, creating custom ticks is indeed the correct approach.

Your custom tick styling code was slightly off (you were actually styling the border stroke of the background, and there was one setColor call out of place). Here's the fixed syntax:

```
axis.addCustomTick()
.setMarker( 
    marker => marker
    .setFont(font => font
        .setSize(25)
    )
    .setBackground(background => background
        .setFillStyle(new SolidFill({ color: ColorHEX('#555555')}))
    )
)
.setValue(3);
```

I understand you were looking for custom ticks logic in a scrolling application, for this we do not have an official example, so I will be expanding this answer shortly with examples how this can be achieved.

CustomTick "length" can be set via a method of its background.

```
background.setPointerLength(5)
```

EDIT:
We'll be adding an official example shortly on custom ticks positioning with scrolling Axis, but here is a code snippet that you can reference for now.
Idea is following Axis interval, creating ticks on key positions, and destroying ticks that go out of view.

```
// * Manage X Axis ticks with custom logic *
// Disable default X ticks.
const xAxis = chart.getDefaultAxisX()
    .setTickStrategy(AxisTickStrategies.Empty)

// Define style for custom ticks.
const gridStrokeStyleMajor = new SolidLine({ thickness: 1, fillStyle: new SolidFill({ color: ColorHEX('#fff').setA(100) }) })
const gridStrokeStyleMinor = new SolidLine({ thickness: 1, fillStyle: new SolidFill({ color: ColorHEX('#fff').setA(50) }) })
const backgroundStrokeStyle = new SolidLine({ thickness: 1, fillStyle: new SolidFill({color: ColorHEX('#fff').setA(50)}) })

const addCustomTickX = (pos, isMinor) => {
    const tick = xAxis.addCustomTick()
        // Set tick text.
        .setTextFormatter(() => String(pos))
        // Set tick location.
        .setValue(pos)
        // Style tick.
        .setMarker(marker => marker
            .setFont(font => font
                .setSize( isMinor ? 12 : 14 )
            )
            .setBackground(background => background
                .setStrokeStyle(backgroundStrokeStyle)
                // "tick length" as pixels.
                .setPointerLength(6)
            )
        )
        .setGridStrokeStyle(isMinor ? gridStrokeStyleMinor : gridStrokeStyleMajor)
    customTicks.push(tick)
    return tick
}

// Create custom ticks on X Axis on realtime scrolling application.
let customTicks = []
const createTicksInRangeX = (start, end) => {
    // Major ticks every 1000 units.
    const majorTickInterval = 1000
    for (let majorTickPos = start - (start % majorTickInterval); majorTickPos <= end; majorTickPos += majorTickInterval) {
        if (majorTickPos >= start) {
            addCustomTickX(majorTickPos, false)
        }
    }
    // Major ticks every 500 units, but not at same interval as major ticks.
    const minorTickInterval = 500
    for (let minorTickPos = start - (start % minorTickInterval); minorTickPos <= end; minorTickPos += minorTickInterval) {
        if (minorTickPos >= start && minorTickPos % majorTickInterval !== 0) {
            addCustomTickX(minorTickPos, true)
        }
    }
}
// X range until which custom ticks are valid.
let customTicksPos = 0
xAxis.onScaleChange((start, end) => {
    // Ensure new ticks are created.
    if (end > customTicksPos) {
        createTicksInRangeX(customTicksPos, end)
        customTicksPos = end
    }

    // Destroy ticks that are out of scrolling range.
    customTicks = customTicks.filter(tick => {
        if (tick.getValue() < start) {
            // Tick is out of view.
            tick.dispose()
            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
    })
})

// Setup X Axis as progressive scrolling.
xAxis
    .setTitle('X Axis (custom ticks)')
    .setInterval(0, 1400)
    .setScrollStrategy(AxisScrollStrategies.progressive)
```

EDIT:
An official example for this kind of application has been added, please find it [here](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-interactive-examples/examples/lcjs-example-0011-customTicksScrolling.html) (Arction website, JS interactive examples).